# Почему не работает z-index?

Tags: html, css3

```css
.knopka {
  z-index: 150;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.spisok {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="spisok">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Текст</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a class="knopka">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

Почему в данном случае не работает z-index? Хочу что бы кнопка выводилась поверх чёрного фона

Comment: z-index работает. У вас кнопка пустая, поэтому её не видно

Comment: Добавил content: ' '; в кнопку, результат тот же

Comment: потому что контент всё-равно пустой. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9uwk77c0/)

Comment: у вас .spisok фиксированный и имеет width 100vw и height 100vh т.е занимает весь viewport и так же имеет background: black а ваша кнопка круглая без текста внутри и имеет полупрозрачную тень чёрного цвета , и не трудно догадаться что чёрный на чёрном не видно , смените у spisok background и увидите свою кнопку

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, спасибо, забыл задать background кнопке )

Answer (score 2):

Добавь в кнопку какой нибудь текст

```
<a class="knopka">
    текст
    <span>или тут текст</span>
</a>
```

И у неё отсутствует фон. Добавьте:

```
.knopka {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```